# Java; while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Problem:

> Consider this data sequence: "3 11 5 5 5 2 4 6 6 7 3 -8". Any value  that is the same as the immediately preceding value  is considered a CONSECUTIVE DUPLICATE. In this example, there are three such consecutive duplicates: the 2nd and 3rd 5s and the second 6. Note that the last 3 is not a consecutive duplicate because it was preceded by a 7. Write some code that uses a loop to read such a sequence of non-negative integers , terminated by a negative number. When the code finishes executing, the number of consecutive duplicates encountered is printed. In this case,3 would be printed.

Correct Answer:

```
int firstNumber, secondNumber, duplicates;
secondNumber = duplicates = 0;
firstNumber = stdin.nextInt();
while (stdin.hasNextInt() && firstNumber > 0 && secondNumber > 0) 
{
    secondNumber = stdin.nextInt();
    if (firstNumber == secondNumber)
    {
                duplicates++;
    }
    firstNumber = secondNumber;
}
System.out.println(duplicates);
```

My question:

Why is `stdin.nextInt()` used when you already have `stdin.hasNextInt()`?

Comment: Because `hasNextInt` determines if calling `nextInt` makes sense to do.

Answer (score 3):

'hasNextInt()' is a function which returns a boolean for the purpose of determining if there is another element in a data structure available. If it returns true then it makes sense to iterate over the while loop again.

'nextInt()' returns the next int in the data structure for use.

Comment: Seems much better suited for a comment, mostly since you're not really explaining why you'd use both, which is the actual question being asked.

Comment: @Matthew disagree. He answered the question, not sure why it would belong in a comment here

Comment: Thank you Canadian Coder for your answer. Thank you Matthew for your response as well. I want to upvote you but I don't have enough points to do so. Thank you though

Comment: In fairness I did make an edit after Matt's comment. Although the answer to this question is so simple that there's really not much more to add.

Comment: I am a new user. Please excuse my novice skills on Stackoverflow and Java. Thank you very much for all your help. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

```
stdin.hasNextInt()
```

Just returns true if there is an integer value ready to be read.

It returns false if there is no value ready, such as if there is no more user input to be read

Answer (score 0):

`hasNextInt` returns boolean, i.e. whether there is a next number or not. So if there is next number then you can call `nextInt` to get it.